# Cannot ask question without adding a tag, but there's no tags, and I require 300 reputation to make a tag!

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm trying to ask the first question on this site, but I'm stuck in a loop causing me not to be able to do anything!

Comment: I guess, that the privilege levels are on public beta level.

Comment: @MEE-ReinstateMonica, yes I was surprised that I would need 300, considering how low the rep requirement is for closing questions. Perhaps they need to switch the rep requirements to private beta level.

Comment: Working on it! Adam's looking at it.

Comment: I also tried to post, and it's saying the same thing to me.

Comment: Tag ideas `dji` `fpv` `pinout` `wiring` `hardware` `software` `betaflight` `frsky` `jumper`

Comment: @Jaakko, yea I tried to add betaflight. That's what my question is about!

Comment: @Jaakko - When suggesting tags, spell them out: [tag:first-person-video] not [tag:fpv] ... you can always point the "fpv" back to the first tag, but for someone uninitiated (new to drones), this will alleviate some confusion.

Comment: @Catija, privileges in general are at the correct levels for a graduated site, not private beta.

Comment: Got a question and answer ready to fire away for documentation, awaiting the same thing here. `tbs, crossfire, crossfire-lite, xlite-pro, unify-pro32-hv, crossfire-nano`

Comment: @Adam I think Meta has correct privilege levels (seeing review queues here), whereas main hasn't.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, good idea, it's much clearer as `first-person-view`.

Comment: @Jaakko - Which goes to show you exactly why you shouldn't use the acronym ... yup, I screwed that up! :o)

Answer (score 12):

I knew it was foolish to think that nothing would break in the 11-something months since the last site launch... and yet I dared hope.

The issue itself is fixed now; sorry about that.

What happened was that a few months ago we redid how we track which state a site is in (Private Beta, Public Beta, etc). Before, whether a site was live or not was a combination of a site state and a boolean to track whether it was "offline". That was replaced with a single list of states that included `Staged` to account for the period of time between when I set the site up in our systems and when it's actually open to the ... private.

Fast forward to privilege calculations. *That* code didn't account for the `Staged` state and happily applied full public privilege levels. Needed to redeploy production to get the updated site state to apply and recalc privileges. Needless to say I'll be fixing the code as well.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you for the detailed explanation!